# Time limits in requesting discovery?

Tags: discovery, time-periods

Is there a time limit for an opposing side to ask for discovery in a civil suit in MA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The court will at some point establish a case-management schedule, which will tell the parties when they need to complete discovery.